# How to generate a random time between two times say 4PM and 2AM?

Tags: java, random, time, java-time, localtime

I have tried using -

```
int startSeconds = restaurant.openingTime.toSecondOfDay();
int endSeconds = restaurant.closingTime.toSecondOfDay();
LocalTime timeBetweenOpenClose = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(startSeconds, endSeconds));
```

But this usually runs into an error as in nextInt(origin, bounds), origin can't be less than bounds which will happen if my `openingTime` is 16:00:00 and `closingTime` is 02:00:00.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that `restaurant.openingTime` and `restaurant.closingTime` are `java.time.LocalTime` too?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Also, 4 PM belongs to today and 2 AM is post-midnight i.e. next day. @OleV.V.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add the seconds of one day(`24*60*60`) when `startSeconds` is greater than `endSeconds` to represent the next day's second and after getting a random number modulo it by the seconds of one day to convert it into LocalTime by a valid second value.

```
int secondsInDay = (int)Duration.ofDays(1).getSeconds();
if(startSeconds > endSeconds){
  endSeconds += secondsInDay;
}
LocalTime timeBetweenOpenClose = LocalTime.ofSecondOfDay(
              ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(startSeconds, endSeconds) % secondsInDay);
```

Answer (score 5):

We cannot know how much time will elapse between 4 PM and 2 AM without applying a date and time zone. Therefore, we will solve it using `ZonedDateTime`.

1. The first step will be: obtain a `ZonedDateTime` by calling [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay-java.time.ZoneId-)

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay(zoneId);
```

2. Next, use [`ZonedDateTime#with`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-) to get a `ZonedDateTime` with the specified time.
3. Now, you can derive an `Instant` from a `ZonedDateTime` using [`ZonedDateTime#toInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/chrono/ChronoZonedDateTime.html#toInstant--).
4. Once you have the start and end `Instant`s derived this way, you can use [`ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextLong-long-long-) to generate a `long` value in the range of the start and the end `Instant`s and use the obtained value to get the required `Instant`.
5. Finally, you can derive a `ZonedDateTime` from this `Instant` using [`Instant#atZone`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#atZone-java.time.ZoneId-) and then get the required time using [`ZonedDateTime#toLocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toLocalTime--).

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Change it as per the applicable timezone e.g. ZoneId.of("Europe/London")
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.systemDefault();
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        
        ZonedDateTime zdtStart = today.atStartOfDay(zoneId)
                                      .with(LocalTime.of(16, 0));
        
        ZonedDateTime zdtEnd = today.plusDays(1)
                                    .atStartOfDay(zoneId)
                                    .with(LocalTime.of(2, 0));
        
        ZonedDateTime zdtResult = 
                Instant.ofEpochMilli(
                            ThreadLocalRandom
                            .current()
                            .nextLong(
                                        zdtStart.toInstant().toEpochMilli(), 
                                        zdtEnd.toInstant().toEpochMilli()
                                    )
                        ).atZone(zoneId);
        
        LocalTime time = zdtResult.toLocalTime();
        System.out.println(time);
    }
}
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

<kbd>[ONLINE DEMO](https://ideone.com/9MVdEY)</kbd> printing 100 random times.

Comment: I suggest adding some explanation of how we cannot know how much time will elapse between 4 PM and 2 AM without applying a date and time zone. Your code is taking steps that, while correct and appropriate, may seem irrelevant to someone with a naïve misunderstanding of date-time handling.

Comment: This is the correct, well explained and recommended answer. From the *usually* in the first sentence of the question I gather a requirement to take both cases into account (a) the restaurant closes before midnight, so the times are on the same day (b) the restaurant closes at or after midnight, the closing time is on the next day. Assuming *today* may not be correct. If one does not know the date, one cannot take summer time transitions and the like into account and will need a different approach.

Comment: @OleV.V. both the requirements you mentioned are correct. While I am able to generate a random time between opening and closing time for case (a), I wasn't able to do so for case (b).

Comment: I am new to the concepts of ZonedDateTime, and Instant so understanding this code is a bit difficult for me right now.

Comment: @VaibhavAgrawal A `ZonedDateTime` is a date and time in a time zone. If you want the time for a particular day and it needs to work correctly in all time zones, then you need this because it takes DST transitions and other time line anomalies into account. An `Instant` is a plain point in time (as the name says). The code converts from `LocalTime` to `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant` to milliseconds in order to do the math on the milliseconds values, then converts back to `Instant` to `ZonedDateTime` to `LocalTime`.

Comment: That's neat @OleV.V. I am getting it now..Thanks!!
And the issue of _origin less than bounds_ gets solved because EpochMilli returns the number of milliseconds from the epoch of _1970-01-01T00:00:00Z_.
Although 4 PM and 2 AM were just examples so rather than hardcoding values `LocalTime.of(16, 0)` instead `restaurant.openingTime` can be used. And `ZonedDateTime zdtEnd = today.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay(zoneId).with(LocalTime.of(2, 0));` can be checked using if condition so that if closingTime falls within same day i.e. `if (openingTime.isBefore(closingTime))` then `plusDays(1)` can be removed.